# Google Cloud Function failed with timeout

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Pub/Sub triggered cloud function that calls an API end-point and logs the message. But I am not seeing all log messages being logged in console except everything right before calling API.
Once the API is called I am logging the response, and exception messages in case of any error. 
It is logging: `Function execution took 120015 ms. Finished with status: timeout` 
 Earlier the default timeout was set to 60 sec, later I increased it to 120 sec. Still the problem persist. 
I am not understanding the issue here since it is working locally without any issues.
Here I have custom module to log messages to Winston and GCP console (it doesn't have any issue and working fine).
**Code calling the API module:**

```
const console = require('./logging-utils');
const portal_api = require('./api-utils');
    
exports.triggerPortalNotifier = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    /*
    .....
    */

      console.metadata.cloudFunction = cf_name;
      console.metadata.requestId = requestId;
      console.metadata.organizationId = organizationId;
      console.metadata.instanceId = instanceId;

      console.logMessage(`Event received with payload: some message`);
      var payload = {
        //payload to API
      }
      var response = await portal_api.notifyPortal(payload);
      console.logMessage(`Response received from portal API is: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);

    }
    else {
      throw new Error(`Invalid message received: ${_message}`);
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.logMessage(`Portal API failed with exception: ${error}`);
    throw new Error(`${error.message}`);
  }
}
```

**Code that make API request (using axios module)**

```
    require('dotenv').config();
const axios = require('./axios-instance');
const console = require('./logging-utils');

const nextgen_api = {
  notifyPortal: async (payload) => {
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': process.env.PORTAL_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN,
          'Content-Type': "application/json",
          'Accept': "application/plain"
        }
      }
      console.logMessage(`Input paylod for API end-point: ${process.env.PORTAL_API} => ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`)
      const response = await axios.post(process.env.PORTAL_API, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(payload)), config);
      console.logMessage(`Response from API: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}`);
      return response;
    }
    catch (err) {
      if (err.response && err.response.status !== 200) {
        console.logMessage(`API call failed with status code: ${err.response.status} `);
        throw new Error(`API call failed with status code: ${err.response.status} `);
      }
      else {
        console.logMessage(`API call failed with ${err.stack}`);
        throw new Error(`API call failed with status code: ${err.stack} `);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = my_api;
```

Message *Response from API: ${JSON.stringify(response.data)}* is not being logged.

Any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74358393/edit) your question and complete code of your cloud function?

Comment: And tell us more about the API that you're calling, too. It sounds like that's timing out, basically. Without knowing anything about what you're calling, it's hard to help.

Comment: @JonSkeet updated question with code snippet.

Comment: So is Axios the API you're calling, or a library used to make API calls? Are you getting the "Input paylod" (sic) message on the console? How long would you normally expect the API call to take? Is it transferring much data?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting Input Payload in console. API would take less than a minute. Not much data, very small piece of JSON data.

Comment: Please check the following links to the documentation with details on Cloud functions timeout :
[Cloud functions quotas and time limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#time_limits) 
[Cloud function timeout](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/timeout)  [Node.js runtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/nodejs-runtime)